# QGIS clipping lines with polygon grid

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip

I have created a uniform (nominally square) gird of polygons using the grid tool.
I have a road network layer that consists of lines. What I would like to do is iterate over the grid polygons and clip the road network within each square.
I can certainly clip the road network out using a single polygon but I would like to automate the process :-) (160+ polygons in the grid!).

Happy to use QGIS 2.14 or 2.18!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use clip tool, from `Processing toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector overlay tools -> Clip`, as follows:

[image]

Select the roads as input layer and grid as clipping layer, and select the green arrow beside the clipping grid

[image]

The output will be clipped roads based on each grid polygon.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My version of qgis doesn't have the 'Vector Overlay Tools' option in Processing->Geoprocessing (neither 2.18.3 or 2.14.11). Where do they come from?

Comment: Ok. Fixed. Had to remove ~/.qgis2. Menus got messed up when installing new version...

Comment: @GlennGeers - Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side of this post :)